# How to visualize large graph?

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I am trying to create a graph where number of nodes is more than 400 which is not visualizing in a proper way.

```
import networkx as nx 
G=nx.MultiGraph() 
G.add_nodes_from(freqItemSet) 
G.add_edges_from([edge]) 
plt.figure(figsize=(10000,10000)) 
nx.draw(G)
```

I was using the above code. Is there any other way to visualize in a proper way.

Thank you

Comment: Try AT&T graphviz.  It's wonderful.  http://www.graphviz.org/  But you might need to rethink your idea about "proper".

Comment: That's great if you can use GraphViz, but @duffymo makes a good point about a 'proper' graph. At some point, without effective zooming in/out, you are going to hit limitations with any graphing software. You can check out [this large graphviz example](http://www.graphviz.org/content/softmaint) or [this large example from networkx](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/examples/drawing/random_geometric_graph.html) to get an idea of graphing large networks

Comment: [And here is a networkx example](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/examples/drawing/lanl_routes.html) that actually even uses graphviz.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called "Gephi" which is free and has good UI.
You can export the file from networkx as "*.gexf" format